# Java: from int to short and from float to short

Tags: java, primitive-types

I know it can't be done,
but since I get those values from somewhere else (...)
and supposing that:

- the int I get is: > 0 and < Short.Max_VALUE;
- the float I get is: > 0 and < Short.Max_VALUE;

How could I perform such a conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you claim that it can't be done?

If you input values are fit into `short` type interval, this will successfully be converted:

```
    int i = 3444;
    short s1 = (short) i;

    float f = 3233.0f;
    short s2 = (short) f;
```

This is called *Narrowing Primitive Conversion*, and described in [JLS Ch. 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

Answer (score 3):

If you know that your `int` (`n`, say) is within the acceptable bounds of the destination type, then you can simply *cast* it:

`short m = (short)n;`

And adopt a similar approach for a `float f`.

`short m = (short)f;`

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand this operation, We have to go back to a book I read long time ago. The concept applied here is called **Narrowing Conversion** which states

> “A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.”

The same concept applies to converting from a double to a float. This conversion can lose precision and range resulting in a zero float from a non zero double and a float infinity is converted to the same signed float.